# Opening a connection to a sqlite database causes file to not be able to be deleted

Tags: sqlite, asp-classic

Writing a classic asp program to allow a user to upload a sqlite file, access information from the file, and then being able to delete the file to upload a newer sqlite file.

After uploading a sqlite database to my server using a third party source, I am able to delete the database both manually (directly from the server using explorer) and using classic asp.  However, once I start a connection to the database, as seen from the code below, I can no longer delete the file even after making sure I close all connections.  I receive, using classic asp, "Permission Denied".  Of course I can stop or recycle the application pool manually by going to the server, but I don't want this to be the solution since the user is on a web page.

I have looked at classic asp examples to recycle the application pool before deleting, but I have not been able to successfully get the code to work correctly.

Currently, permissions to the folder where the database is located has admin, system, everyone, users and the owner (myself).

Below is a short code example of after the file has been uploaded, and the code is executed, the file gets locked and cannot be deleted manually or by classic asp until application pool is recycled.  Once the code is executed, and I try to delete the file using classic asp, I receive a "Permission Denied".

Any suggestions?  I definitely would like this to work using only classic asp.  The file only becomes locked after a connection below is made.

```
set hotAirOconn=server.createobject ("ADODB.connection")
hotAirOconn.open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=C:/lindsey/webPages/azAirVentures/database/textfiles_AZAirVentures/hotAir/hotAirDatabase_2.sqlite;LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;   "

hotAirOconn.close
set hotAirOconn=nothing
```

Comment: Are you using `Option Explicit` to guard against typo'd identifiers?

Comment: Would that be a parameter that goes inside of the "HotAirOconn.open" statement.  If so, could you give me an example of how to implement that option.  I'll play with it to see if that's where it goes until I get some feedback.  Not an expert at opening connections.  I just did change the connection string to "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=C:/lindsey/webPages/azAirVentures/database/textfiles_AZAirVentures/hotAir/hotAirDatabase_2.sqlite;LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0; option explicit;".  It did run but still the file is locked.

Comment: No, `Option Explicit` is a VBScript option you put at the very first line of code in each `.asp` file.

Comment: After creating a simple test page, adding that option did not work.  Thanks.

Comment: @Greg Is this code just in a page or is it part of `Session_Start()` in the `global.asa` file?

Comment: Just in the page.  I found a code to rewrite the web.config file, just by reading it and then writing to the file to force a reload of the application pool.  Seems to work 80% of the time.  No consistency.  So still looking for a solution.